# Kubernetes deployment: Don't terminate pod until new pod has been in Running state for 2 minutes

Tags: kubernetes

When I do `kubectl delete pod` or `kubectl patch`, how can I ensure that the old pod doesn't actually delete itself until the replacement pod has been running for 2 minutes? (And if the replacement pod dies before the 2 minute mark, then don't even delete the old pod)

The reason is that my initiation takes about 2 minutes to pull some latest data and run calculations; after 2 minutes it'll reach a point where it'll either error out or continue running with the updated calculations.

I want to be able to occasionally delete the pod so that it'll restart and get new versions of stuff (because getting new versions is only done at the beginning of the code).

Is there a way I can do this without an init container? Because I'm concerned that it would be difficult to pass the calculated results from the init container to the main container

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to provide an endpoint for getting new versions in the running container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to tweak **two** parameters.

- We have set the `minReadySeconds` as 2 min. Or we can use `readiness probe` instead of hardcoded 2min.
- We have to do **rolling update** with `maxSurge > 0 (default: 1) and maxUnavailable: 0`. This will bring the new pod(s) and **only if it becomes ready**, old pod(s) will be killed. This process continues for rest of the pods.

> Note: 0 <= maxSurge <= replicaCount

Comment: Is maxSurge needed? It seems like if we just set maxUnavailable: 0, won't that be enough?

Comment: @gunit Thanks. maxSurge have default value of 1. So we don't have to specify. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hey. I have a question about how to do the opposite of this. I have a situation where I prefer downtime to having 2+ pods running at the same time. I've tried making maxSurge: 0 and maxUnavailable: 1, but i'm still seeing this behavior

Comment: Note: I've also tried the `Recreate` strategy and using either deployment strategies (Recreate and RollingUpdate with maxSurge: 0 and maxUnaavailable: 1). In both cases, after deleting a pod, the replacement will come up in about 3 seconds, but take about 30-60 seconds to completely terminate. I’m trying to avoid any overlap at all

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Deployment, you can set `minReadySeconds` in the spec to 120 (seconds). Kubernetes will not consider it actually ready and in service (and therefore spin down old pods) until the pod reports it has been ready for that long.